# Black diamond question mark character on page when UTF8 header sent

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an old database on a MySQL 4.1 server, the db contains some user inputted content, I have copied this database to a new MySQL 5 server and when I view a page where the content is printed, I see the black diamond character with question mark in the middle. This only shows on the new server.

If I add this header to the page, the diamond no longer shows:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

If I take out that header, then the server sends a default header which looks like below, and the diamond re-appears

> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF8

How can I resolve this in the db (e.g. some sort of conversion on the tables), so that I don't have to put this header in all of my pages?

More info: I used a mysqldump to export the database from the old server, then used the CentOS mysql command line to import it. I have also tried exporting using phpMyAdmin but it's the same result.

Edit:

Looking at my mysqldump file, I can see that all of the CREATE TABLE statements have the charset = Latin1, so I think what I'm looking for is a way to export the database in UTF8 instead. I have tried adding this option to mysqldump but it didn't have any effect, the dump still shows Latin1:

> --default-character-set=utf8

Comment: It means the data returned from the database is encoded in Latin1, not UTF-8, therefore your get an encoding mismatch. See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: @deceze I think you're right, see my edit. Is there any way to go about exporting Latin1 data as UTF8?

Comment: It is probably not necessary to convert your database, you can simply tell the connection object which character set you expect (before doing the query). See the already given answers, or have a look [here](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the charset after connecting to your database:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Answer (score 3):

What Trevor said worked for me except with Mysqli.

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Answer (score 1):

use below query after connection mysql database.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Hope this help!